# unable to open page througt url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, wampserver, netbeans-8

i am unable to open page through url

i am able to open **hello.blade.php** page through

```
**http://localhost:88/laravel/public/**
```

and i want to open about.blade.php page using url like

```
**http://localhost:88/laravel/public/about**
```

when i opening this page i am geting this error msg

> The requested URL /laravel/public/about was not found on this server.

pls help me

my code is

**hello.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome in to laravel frame work </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1> Hello, welcome to the home page </h1>
        <h2> hello, {{  $name }}

    </body>
```

**about.blade.php**

```
<html>
    <head><title> About </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is the About page</h1>

    </body>
        </html>
```

**pagecontroller.php**

```
<?php


class pagecontroller extends BaseController
{
    public function home()
   {
        $name = "jitender kumar malav";
        return View::make('hello')->with('name', $name);
    }

    public function about()
    {
        return View::make('about');
    }
   }
```

**route.php**

```
<?php


Route::get('/', 'pagecontroller@home');

Route::get('/about', 'pagecontroller@about');
```

Comment: We need more information here, on what errors you receive if any, server logs etc. Please expand your question.

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file in your public folder, if so what does it contain? If not add it!

Comment: yes i have .htacces file in my public folder and inside this file have some code like <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>